# Angular JS - Key Binding on Directive Calls Function But Doesn't Affect Ng-Show State

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular controller with a variable in it that controls whether a `div` is shown using `ng-show`:

```
myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){

  $scope.flag = false;

  $scope.changeFlag = function(){
    console.log("function is called");
    $scope.flag = !$scope.flag;
  };

});
```

I added a directive that listens for a key stroke on the `escape` key and then calls the `$scope.changeFlag()` function once a keyup is detected.

```
myApp.directive("closeIt", function(){
  return{
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.bind("keyup", function(event){
        if(event.which == 27){
          console.log("escape has been pressed");
          scope.changeFlag();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

These two things come together in the below HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <body ng-controller="myController" close-it>
    <div ng-show="flag">
      Something here
    </div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="changeFlag()">
      This works
    </button>
  </body>
<html>
```

I bound the `$scope.changeFlag()` function to a button and this works as expected.  When I press my keyboard's `escape` key, the console log messages in both the directive and controller function are called.  The `$scope.flag` is also changed.  But my `div` element does not show / hide.

Is this a bug within Angular?  If so, is there a way to get around it?

[Plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XKiHAaF7iySJ3YZ4JlRw?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/i7m7lkEJwE9FZA0oxjni?p=preview)

Wrap your 'keyup' handler in an $apply. When you bind to jQuery events, you can call $apply to let angular know to trigger a $digest cycle.

```
myApp.directive("closeIt", function(){
  return{
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.bind("keyup", function(event){
        scope.$apply(function() {
        if(event.which == 27){
          console.log("escape has been pressed");
          scope.changeFlag();
        }

        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```